# Which Git/bitbucket Repositories structure choose for Parse Projects with CloudCode + AndroidStudio?

Tags: git, android-studio, parse-platform, bitbucket

I have a Parse Project that includes an Android application developed on AndroidStudio and some JavaScript Parse Cloud code (+web hosting). I'm using Git on Bitbucket for Versioning.  I'm wondering how to organize my Repository(ies) in order to:

- Have separate commits between  the 2 sub projects: cloud code and Android code (in order to have easy revert from each subprojects …)
- Have some common release between these both subprojects (that must works together obviously).
- Have a common Parent directory to simply check out the both sub-projects

If I use a single Repository (in a parent directory) like this:

```
Parent-platformDir
                 /.git
                /myAndroidStudioProject
                /myCloudCodeApp
```

Then when I link AndroidStudio to this Git VCS it will detect all the cloud code modifications and I might mix the commit between these 2 subprojects.

I know there are some features like Gitsubmodule of Gitsubtree, but it's not clear at all and I'm afraid that it doesn't suit to my need.

So which kind of Git Repository architecture suit best?

Comment: Just a comment, this is the sort of reason people just use subversion.   (Just use different folders, no big deal, it's a non issue.).  If you're on PC, once you try Tortoise with a subversion repo (or on a mac, VersionsApp with a subversion repo), it's hard to go back. Git is an astounding piece of software, beloved of "geeks" and "technical specialists".  But the *whole point* of git technology is it was made to solve a problem ("very low bandwidth use!") which is just totally, utterly irrelevant today.  svn exists for a reason, it is indeed the new, easy-to-use source control.

Comment: So there is no nice design suitable for the use case with GIT ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but subversion is just **much easier** and more popular for Unity (and indeed any game, film, audio projects).  Just get an xp-dev account (for example, any svn repo) and on PC use Tortoise.  By the way you realise that with Unity projects you **only commit the Assets folder and the Settings folder** to source control, nothing else.  You can google many many pages about using source control with Unity. Hope it helps!